# PHP - same things different output( if else )

Tags: php, if-statement

I could not solve one mysterious thing and right now I somehow solved it so I want to ask you where was the problem.

First code I wrote was this one and it was not working:

```
    <?php
    if( ! isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) )
    {
?>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="login" method="post" action="../login/login.php">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"/><br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password"/><br>
                <?php
                    if( isset( $_SESSION['error'] ) )
                        echo $error;
                ?>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
<?php } ?>

<?php   else
        {
            unset( $_SESSION['error'] );
?>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>PHP Quizzer</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>This is a PHP quizzer.</h2>
            <p>This is a multiple choice quiz to test your knowledge of PHP</p>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Number of Questions: </strong></li>
                <li><strong>Type: </strong>Multiple Choice</li>
                <li><strong>Estimated Time: </strong></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="questions.php?n=1" class="start">Start Quiz</a>
        </div>
    </main>
<?php } ?>
```

And the second code that I have just written is the one which works and I do not know why:

```
<?php
    if( ! isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) )
    {
?>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="login" method="post" action="../login/login.php">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"/><br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password"/><br>
                <?php
                    if( isset( $_SESSION['error'] ) )
                        echo $error;
                ?>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
<?php }
    else
        {
            unset( $_SESSION['error'] );
?>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>PHP Quizzer</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>This is a PHP quizzer.</h2>
            <p>This is a multiple choice quiz to test your knowledge of PHP</p>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Number of Questions: </strong></li>
                <li><strong>Type: </strong>Multiple Choice</li>
                <li><strong>Estimated Time: </strong></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="questions.php?n=1" class="start">Start Quiz</a>
        </div>
    </main>
<?php } ?>
```

Can you guys tell me where was the problem? The only thing I did is that I merged `}` and `else{ unset( $_SESSION['error'] ) )` in the middle of code.

**EDIT**: First code outputs completely blank page. The second code outputs exactly what is written in the code.

Comment: If you use a service like Bitbucket.com and SourceTree application it will let you know after saves/commits where the code changed for situations like this.

Comment: @Levi Thank you, I am going to try that.

Comment: No problem. Bitbucket.com is similar to Github as well so you can have options. However bitbucket allows free private repositories so thats nice for budgetary reasons.

Comment: @Levi I do not think it is what I wanted. I asked what is the difference between these 2 codes. Those two codes have exactly the same texts but first has one `php` section more than the second.

Comment: **HOW** is the output different between these two? if no other code was changed except merging the two php blocks into a single one for the `else`,. the only difference would be the blank line you have between the two blocks.

Comment: Sry guys: the first code outputs blank page. The second one outputs the page with the content I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is by closing } ?> you then output whitespace and than the else keyword. It would be similar to

```
if (condition) {
    // do stuff
}
print '    ';
else { ....
```

which does not make sense

Comment: Not really but something similar. It doesnt really outputs whitespace. I think that it is just a matter of syntax.

Comment: Yes it does output whitespace. Anything between ?> and <?php even whitespace (including newlines) is output

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned code, you did not set the value of session variable "user". Because of this reason, page always shows user login page part. The correct code is mentioned below.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if( isset($_REQUEST["submit"]) === true ) {
  $_SESSION['user'] = trim($_REQUEST["username"]);
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php
        if( ! isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) )
        {
    ?>
        <main>
            <div class="container">
                <form class="login" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"/><br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password"/><br>
                    <?php
                        if( isset( $_SESSION['error'] ) )
                            echo $error;
                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/><br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    <?php }
        else
            {
                unset( $_SESSION['error'] );
    ?>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>PHP Quizzer</h1>
            </div>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div class="container">
                <h2>This is a PHP quizzer.</h2>
                <p>This is a multiple choice quiz to test your knowledge of PHP</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><strong>Number of Questions: </strong></li>
                    <li><strong>Type: </strong>Multiple Choice</li>
                    <li><strong>Estimated Time: </strong></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="questions.php?n=1" class="start">Start Quiz</a>
            </div>
        </main>
    <?php } ?>


  </body>
</html>
```